# In Android Sqlite is ROWID same as primary Key?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a table with the following schema :

```
public static final String PRIMARY_KEY = "_id";
public static final String TASK_NAME = "name";
public static final String TASK_DESCRIPTION = "description";
public static final String IS_TASK_COMPLETED = "is_completed";
public static final String IS_TASK_DELETED = "is_deleted";
public static final String TASK_START_DATE = "start_date";
public static final String TASK_START_TIME = "start_time";
public static final String ESTIMATED_TASK_END_DATE = "end_date";
public static final String TIMESTAMP = "timestamp";
```

In one fragment I'm inserting a row in the table using the [`insert()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29]) method. I know that this returns the `rowId` of the inserted row but in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246649/why-cant-you-use-sqlite-rowid-as-a-primary-key) thread I read that

> If a table contains a column of type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, then that
>   column becomes an alias for the ROWID. You can then access the ROWID
>   using any of four different names, the original three names described
>   above or the name given to the INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column. All these
>   names are aliases for one another and work equally well in any
>   context.

So will the returning rowId be same as the primary key. But what if a row is deleted and another row is inserted in that case will the `rowId` be as same as the `primary key value "id"`?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Are you asking what happens to the `rowId` if you delete a record and then do an `INSERT`?

Comment: Yes. I mean will the value of rowId and the primary key will always be same?

Comment: Still not clear...but if you make the column integer and primary key, then `rowId` should be synonomous with the primary key.

Comment: If I have a row in the table having rowId value as 8 and primary key value as 8. If I delete this row and insert another row. The value of new PK will be 9. What will be the value of new rowId?

Comment: If you had an integer PID column, then SQLite _might_ use `9` as the next value.  But it could also use another value if you don't have the column set to auto increment.  But all bets are off, because you have a `String` PID column.

Comment: Thanks Tim, that clears my doubt.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All tables (ignoring [exceptions](http://www.sqlite.org/withoutrowid.html)) have a row ID.

When there is no column declared as INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, the `rowid` is separate from the other columns:

```
CREATE TABLE A ( _id INT PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT ); -- not "INTEGER"

| rowid | _id | name |
+-------+-----+------+
|     1 |   1 | this |
|     2 |   2 | that |
|     3 |  30 | NULL |  -- does not need to be the same
```

If there *is* an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column, both `rowid` and the declared column name are aliases for the *same* value:

```
CREATE TABLE B ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT );

| rowid | name |
| = _id |      | 
+-------+------+
|     1 | this |
|     2 | that |
|     3 | NULL |
```